# sendmail on centos drops connection after n e-mails sent

Tags: centos, vps, sendmail

I have a centos box (vps) with sendmail and I am using it to send a newsletter to mail clients. I am using a machine in my local network to send the e-mails via SMTP (AUTH PLAIN) but after sending some e-mail (35 .. 50) the connection starts to get closed by the server (centos/sendmail).

I've searched Google for a limit configuration on number of e-mails in sendmail but didn't find anything.

What configuration can I use to allow me to send more e-mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked sendmail log files for reaction to too high system load?
[I have assumed "customized" newsletter - one "personalized" email per one recipient]

Possible fixes:

Custom mailing list software (as recommended by adamo)

**OR**

- Increase confQUEUE_LA (default=8 per processor) and confREFUSE_LA (default=12 per processor) **if your server can handle it**
- Configure confDELAY_LA (I would suggest 9) to make sendmail slow messages acceptance
- introduce delays in email sending e.g. 1-2 seconds after every 10 messages

Comment: Welcome to SF Andrzej!  Since this is a VM, I am assuming that in the case of a single mail per recipient, this will be queued locally by a web (php) form, so it might be a good idea to follow Vixie's advice and have QUEUE_LA and REFUSE_LA have the reverse values (deny accepting connections in order to clear the queue first).

Comment: I personally prefer accepting **ham** e-mail in most situations. You can fine tune sendmail/server under your control to minimize delivery delays. I would like to achieve delivery of at least 90%/95% of non bulk e-mail below 5 minutes limit (standard for 2013).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to read the [configuration README](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/). In there you will read aout settings your can put in the `/etc/mail/acceess` database that rate limit connections to your host. ClientConn: and ClientRate: are the ones.

You also need to check confMAX_RCPTS_PER_MESSAGE.

However, since you are sending a newsletter, you are better off managing this by installing appropriate software like say [Mailman](http://www.list.org)